# Incrementing Numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, prime-numbers

I want to take a prime number p0 = 3, add 2 to it to get a new number p1 = 5, then add four to p1 to get p2, then add 6 to p2 to get p3, etc for a total of 50 times. How do I do that and place my results in a table?

Comment: `FoldList[Plus, 3, 2 * Range[50]]`?

Comment: ^ or equivalent to above `Prepend[Accumulate[2 Range[50]] + 3, 3]`

Comment: Trading in a Prepend for a Range modification  `Accumulate[2 Range[0, 50]] + 3`

Answer (score 6):

From the question we can easily deduce the sequence

```
s = {3, 5, 9, 15};
```

With `FindSequenceFunction` we get

```
FindSequenceFunction[s, n]
```

3 - n + n^2

Now we can do

```
3 - # + #^2 & /@ Range[10]
```

{3, 5, 9, 15, 23, 33, 45, 59, 75, 93}

Or directly

```
(n |-> Evaluate @ FindSequenceFunction[s, n]) @ Range[10]
```

{3, 5, 9, 15, 23, 33, 45, 59, 75, 93}

Test

```
% == FoldList[Plus, 3, 2 Range[9]]
```

True

Answer (score 3):

```
l = Range[9];
```

---

Using `Table` and `Take`:

```
Table[2*Total[Take[#, n]] + 3, {n, 0, Length@#}] &@l

(*{3, 5, 9, 15, 23, 33, 45, 59, 75, 93}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

Also (from https://oeis.org/A027688):

```
Table[Fibonacci[3, n] + n + 2, {n, 0, 9}]
```

> `{3, 5, 9, 15, 23, 33, 45, 59, 75, 93}`

Answer (score 2):

(**Edited**) Perhaps the OP requires something like the following?

```
Reap[Nest[Sow[Sow[Sow[# + 2] + 4] + 6] &, Sow[3], 50]][[2, 1]];

% // Short

(* {{3, 5, 9, 15, 17, 21, 27, 29, 33, 39, 41, <<129>>,
     561, 567, 569, 573, 579, 581, 585, 591, 593, 597, 603} *)
```

---

Leaving out the starting number (`3`) to better visualise the interpretation

"Start with 3, (add 2, add 4, add 6), (add 2, add 4, add 6), ..."

```
Reap[Nest[Sow[Sow[Sow[# + 2] + 4] + 6] &, 3, 10]][[2, 1]] 
 // Partition[#, 3] &

(* {
    {5, 9, 15}, 
    {17, 21, 27}, 
    {29, 33, 39}, 
    {41, 45, 51}, 
    {53, 57, 63}, 
    {65, 69, 75}, 
    {77, 81, 87}, 
    {89, 93, 99}, 
    {101, 105, 111}, 
    {113, 117, 123}
   } *)
```